# Save multiple records created from a range of dates in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-2.x

I have to get the date range for start & end dates selected by the user, check the date doesn't fall on weekends and/or public holidays and insert into database for each valid date till the end date.

Below is my code:

```
$aryRange=array();

$istartTime=mktime(1,0,0,substr($startTime,5,2),     substr($startTime,8,2),substr($startTime,0,4));
$iendTime=mktime(1,0,0,substr($endTime,5,2),     substr($endTime,8,2),substr($endTime,0,4));

if ($iendTime>=$istartTime)
{
    array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$istartTime)); // first entry
    while ($istartTime<$iendTime)
    {
        $istartTime+=86400; // add 24 hours
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$istartTime));
    }
}

$aryRange = array_values($aryRange);

$dates = array($aryRange);

$fdate = strtotime($startTime);
$day = date("N",$fdate);


$holidays = $this->Leave->PublicHoliday->find ('all', array('fields'=>array('PublicHoliday.SetDate')));


foreach($dates as $key => $value)
{
    if ($day == 7 || $day == 6)
    {
        unset ($dates[$k]);
        continue;

    }
    if (in_array($value, $holidays))
    {
        unset ($dates[$k]);
        continue;
    }

}
```

I don't know how will I assign start date and end date for each entry and save the data. I think this can be done within the `foreach` loop.

```
$this->request->data['Leave']['event_date'] = $value[0];
$this->request->data['Leave']['event_stop_time'] = $value[0];
$this->Leave->save($this->request->data);
```

Can I save row by row as the `foreach` loop executes? Any help on saving the data is very much appreciated.

NB:
`event_date` will be similar to `event_stop_time` for a single day.

Comment: What version of cake are you using? I can't really provide you a great answer without that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($istarTime), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($iendTime));
$holidays = $this->Leave->PublicHoliday->find('list', array('fields'=>array('PublicHoliday.SetDate')));

foreach ($period as $date) {
    if ($date->format('N') < 6 && !in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
        $data[] = ['Leave' => [
            'event_date' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
            'event_stop_time' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
        ]];
    }
}

$this->Leave->saveMany($data);
```

The above should work if `PublicHoliday.SetDate` is a `DATE` field in your database.